# Find sub image in a large image using JAVA and FAST algorithm

Tags: java, performance, image-processing

I am very new to image processing and my requirement is to detect whehter the given large image consist the given subimage (small image) using Java and FAST algorithm. I have found the java lib (jfeaturelib) which support APIs for FAST algorithms and other descriptors etc.

Follwing link is from jfeaturelib which explaing how to get features of a image using decriptors and I cound run this code and get the features of both the images.
https://github.com/locked-fg/JFeatureLib-Demo/tree/master/src/main/java/de/lmu/dbs/ifi/jfeaturelib/examples

But as jfeaturelib documention didn't provide sufficient information on useage of the API I feel helpless.
It would be a great help if some one can guide me on how to use these set of APIs to achive my requiement.

If some one can atleast tell me the major steps which are requied to deal with this task.( That is getting the images features etc.)

Thanks.

Anybody have the answer for this?

Comment: Did you tried contacting the devs of JFeatureLib??

Comment: I tried, still waiting for their response. Anyway I can go for alternative libraries like Fiji or ImageJ if I get proper guide.

Answer (score 0):

Probably already out of date, but either you asked already on the mailinglist or I never got your request. JFeatueLib is for feature **extraction** only.

Matching and finding subimages is usually the next step in the image processing pipeline. Also it is totally different from extraction as it usally involves distance measures, clustering, hashing and modeling. A commonly method is: applying a RANSAC algorithm to finding and matching similar vectors. AS you can see, simple matching / finding subimages is yet another problem domain. This is why JFeatureLib simply doesn't cover this topic.

---

Edit in 2018:
btw you could also use the masking feature of JFeatureLib: https://github.com/locked-fg/JFeatureLib/wiki/HowTo#using-masks
Yet not all Descriptors support masking. Please check https://github.com/locked-fg/JFeatureLib/wiki/FeaturesOverview for the supported capabilities (look for 'Masking' in the capabilities).